# How i validate when one textbox value lessthan another textbox value??/

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller

i am using the below code which data save successfully on ajax,, but i want when Level Price is lessthan Avg Cost then its should not be accept the value, if greater then its save the data. how i do this.. plz help me.

```js
  //Create Function for Save Data On Ajax//
    function SaveData(id) {


        var prdid = $("#prd_id").val();
        var levelprice = $("#levelprice_" + id).val();
        var avg = $("#avg_" + id).val();
        var sell = $("#QTYsprice_" + id).val();

        if (Number(levelprice.val()) < Number(avg.val())) {

            alert("This item cannot be sale...");

            $("#levelprice_" + id).focus();
            return false;
        }

        else {

            $("#prf_" + id).val(levelprice - avg);
            $("#prfngt_" + id).val((((levelprice - avg) / avg) * 100).toFixed(2));
            $("#dscamt_" + id).val((sell - levelprice).toFixed(2));
            $("#dscntg_" + id).val((((sell - levelprice) / levelprice) * 100).toFixed(2));


            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                data: { typeid: id, levelP: levelprice, id: prdid },
                url: '@Url.Action("Update_Cust_Level", "Products")',
                success: function (result) {

                }

            });

        }
    }
```

thanks

regards,

Tahir

Comment: you have already get value. use condition like this  `if (Number(levelprice) < Number(avg))`

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use .text() or .html() in place of .val() to get content of the div tag using jquery.  Try this...

```
            //Create Function for Save Data On Ajax//
        function SaveData(id) {


            var prdid = $('#prd_id').text();  
            var levelprice = $("#levelprice_" + id).text();
            var avg = $("#avg_" + id).text();
            var sell = $("#QTYsprice_" + id).text();

            if (Number(levelprice) < Number(avg)) {

                alert("This item cannot be sold...");

                $("#levelprice_" + id).focus();
                return false;
            }

            else {
                $("#prf_" + id).text() * (levelprice - avg);
                $("#prfngt_" + id).text() * (((levelprice - avg) / avg) * 100).toFixed(2);
                $("#dscamt_" + id).text() * (sell - levelprice).toFixed(2);
                $("#dscntg_" + id).text() * ((((sell - levelprice) / levelprice) * 100).toFixed(2));


                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: { typeid: id, levelP: levelprice, id: prdid },
                    url: '@Url.Action("Update_Cust_Level", "Products")',
                    success: function (result) {

                    }

                });

            }
        }
```

Hope this helps....

Answer (score 0):

Change you `if condition`

```
if (Number(levelprice.val()) < Number(avg.val())) {
                            .
                            .
                            .
```

to

```
   if (Number(levelprice) < Number(avg)) {
                                .
                                .
                                .
```

Comment: Sir, i tried it but its not worked.. any more help plz

Comment: is there is any error or something... and also  alert your  levelprice and avg ,check its correct value or not.